# Gulp task not accessing karma.conf.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, karma-runner, gulp-karma

I am using following gulp task to execute the karma/jasmine unit test cases . however i was not able access the karma.conf.js file for some reason. this problem occurs when i use this `path`package to access the karma.conf.js file.

**gulp task**

```
gulp.task('tdd', function (done) {
      karma.start({
        configFile: fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '../Tests/karma.conf.js')),
        singleRun: true
      }, done);
    });
```

error i am getting

```
PS C:\Users\dell pc\Documents\Work\WebApiRole> gulp tdd
[13:47:58] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\Work\WebApiRole\Gulpfile.js
[13:47:58] Starting 'tdd'...
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.32 server started at http://localhost:9876/
```

It just wait forever in above state .

But when just access the file like this `configFile: __dirname, '../Tests/karma.conf.js'` (without **fs.readFile(path.join**) then the gulp access the `karma.conf.js` file successfully .

can someone give me an idea regarding what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`configFile` property is just a file name. So when you provide `__dirname + '../Tests/karma.conf.js'` it corresponds to the actual file location. You can actually do:

```
configFile: path.join(__dirname, '../Tests/karma.conf.js')
```

With `fs.readFile` you read a file and provide its contents to the karma runner. I am not sure why you are not getting any error.

Comment: Thank you . this issue bugged me for several hours . I was under the impression that fs.readFile access the file .

Comment: Thank you so much @zaynetro This fixed a headache! Karma really needs to document a tutorial for different scenarios.